# Node JS update specific cell in CSV given the header column name in CSV

Tags: javascript, node.js

I checked various node modules for updating specific cell in CSV given the header column name from the CSV.

I could not find an example and which node module to use.

Answer (score -1):

Use node module [xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)

```
npm install xlsx
```

Use below logic to access desire cell from workbook

```
var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
var address_of_cell = 'A1';

/* Get worksheet */
var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];

/* Find desired cell */
var desired_cell = worksheet[address_of_cell];

/* Get the value */
var desired_value = desired_cell.v;
```

Comment: var workbook = XLSX.readFile('Data.csv'); I get 'Error: Unsupported file 82'